# Update the datatable without using DataAdapter.Fill 2 times

Tags: c#, mysql, data-access-layer

I am writing a program to manage a office. (Getting rid of Excels XD).

I have a DAL class with the following variables:

```
    private MySqlConnection connection;
    private DataSet ds;
    private Hashtable adapters;
```

There is this method:

```
    public bool AddTable(string tableName, string sqlStat)
    {
        if (!ds.Tables.Contains(tableName))
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sqlStat, connection);
            MySqlCommandBuilder builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
            adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
            adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
            adapter.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand();
            adapter.Fill(ds, tableName);
            adapters.Add(tableName, adapter);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The program will be connected to a server with MySQL database.
I need to make sure that when one client changes something in the database another client will see the new data, but this is not happening.

Comment: We need more information. What is the UpdateCommand? How does the other client select the (recently updated) data?

Comment: There are multiply instances of the program running in the same time. both opening the same table. the program shows them all the information. (They see the same table). Then one of them editing the table and saving. (MySQL_Database has the edits saved). Now :: The second one will not see the edits that were made until he will restart the program. I need, want and must to make that the second one will only need to refresh the form that showing the table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on optimistic concurrency, which helps solve the problem of multiple users reading and updating the same data at the same time.

I suggest you start here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114262/6-ways-of-doing-locking-in-NET-Pessimistic-and-opt

Comment: I have no idea how. but after I read microsoft's information about this subject I Now have this error in my code while there is only one instance of the program that is running.   I thought that there is a problem in the automatic-update-command but I checked the parameters and I see no problem..